# Radical containments $R(X) \subset R(Y) \implies Y \subset X$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This should be fairly simple, but i am missing something obvious. By the containment $R(X) \subset R(Y)$, there is integer $n,$ such that $w^n \in X$ and $w^m \in Y$. Here $X, Y$ are ideals of a ring say $A.$

If $n \leq m$, this is true, but I can't figure out how to proceed on $n > m.$

Comment: The statement is false. Let $A$ be nonzero. Then the radical of the zero ideal is contained in the radical of the unit ideal... Did you mean $R(X) \subseteq R(Y)$ implies $X \subseteq Y$?

Comment: No this little part is used to inside the argument to prove $r(X + Y) = r(r(X) + r(Y))$. On $r(X + Y) \supset r(r(X) + r(Y)) \implies X + Y \subset r(X) + r(Y).$ But a moment of thought made me remember we always have $X \subset r(X)$ by definition.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false. If $X$ and $Y$ are ideals and $X\subset Y$, then also $r(X)\subset r(Y)$; if your conjecture were true , you’d conclude $X=Y$.

On the other hand, neither the other inclusion can be deduced, as $r(r(X))=r(X)$. Taking $X$ a nonradical ideal and $Y=r(X)$ would provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $r(X+Y)\subseteq r(r(X)+r(Y))$, use that $X\subseteq r(X)$ and $Y\subseteq r(Y)$. For the reverse inclusion, note that $X, Y\subseteq X+Y$ and $r(r(I))=r(I)$ for any ideal $I$.